# How do i change the password of root, using webmin in one command line?

Tags: command-line, security, root, password-recovery, permissions

I have lost root password of one old server, where i can only have normal user login and via webmin login. Via webmin interface i have one option to execute command, i have been trying the following but it fails:

```
> echo -e "newPassword\nnewPassword" | passwd root"
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
> whoami
root
```

via webmin, i can see i am logged in as `root`

Comment: Have a look at this page: [How to reset Webmin root password](http://akyl.net/how-reset-webmin-root-password) Hopefully it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `passwd` instead of `passwd root` (or `echo -e "newPassword\nnewPassword" | passwd root"`). Moreover, your command have an unexpected '`"`' at the end too.

Answer (score 1):

```
line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

That makes sense. Any time you have three quotes in a command line without any backslashes, you're asking for trouble. Those things are supposed to come in pairs.

```
echo -e "newPassword\nnewPassword" | passwd root
```

That's kinda clunky. I don't think it can work. It certainly doesn't for me.

This is a little better, but still bad:

```
usermod -p $(echo "newPassword" | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) root
```

Update: learned about `chpasswd` today:

```
echo "root:password" | chpasswd
```

Comment: `echo "root:password" | chpasswd` worked like a charm!